# Extend Laravel 4.1 validation class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I try extend Validator class. I need add a few methods, that I'd like extend all class not use `Validator::extend();`

I added in vendor direcotry structure:

```
-comjaroapp
 -src
  -Comjaroapp
   -Validation
    -Validator.php
    -ValidatorServiceProvider.php
```

In my config/app.php in providers array, I added:

```
'Comjaroapp\Validation\ValidatorServiceProvider'
```

Code to test is simple:

Validator:

```
    namespace Comjaroapp\Validation;
class CustomValidator extends \Illuminate\Validation\Validator{
    public function validatePesel($attribute,$value,$options=null){
        return true;
    }
}
```

ValidatorServiceProvider:

```
namespace Comjarospp\Validation;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class ValidatorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
    public function register(){}

    public function boot(){
        $this->app->validator->resolver(function($transator,$data,$rules,$messages){
            return new CustomValidator($transator,$data,$rules,$messages);
        });
    }
}
```

After run composer update I see error:

```
> Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class
> 'Comjaroapp\Validation\ValidatorServiceProvider' not found in
> /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php
> on line 158
```

When I looked on other extension all work with same structure.

If someone have idea, what is wrong or when should I search, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have different names for your namespaces:

```
Comjarospp\Validation
```

and

```
Comjaroapp\Validation
```

**EDIT:**

After fixing the namespace name, have you executed

```
composer dumpautoload
```

?

Comment: True, it's so stupid error. Thanks. But fixed not solve my problem. Still I have same error after name space changed.

Comment: Since you have fixed the namespace, if you are not using PSR-0 or PSR-4, you need to execute `composer dumpautoload`. Edited.

Comment: I moved to psr-4 and class is loaded. But now is problem with "make". In instance CustomValidator is error `Call to undefined method CustomValidator::make` when I use Validator class. Is error that validationPesel not exist (it's logical).

Comment: I was rename Validator to CustomValidator, because I thought that same class name as laravel class is problem.

Now after edit my post, you can see it.

Comment: \Illuminate\Validation\Validator doesnt have a make method, Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider uses Factory and you will also need a Facade to use it this way, so you have to review all of this code.